# What is the purpose of OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS concurrency mode?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode documents three concurrency mode options: OPTIMISTIC, OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS, AND PESSIMISTIC.
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#concurrency_modes

It seems that OPTIMISTIC is the recommended mode, but when my Legacy Datastore was automatically upgraded to Cloud Firestore in Datastore, it was automatically set to OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS. I am sometimes getting the following error:
`google.api_core.exceptions.Aborted: 409 too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.`

I'm considering to switch to OPTIMISTIC, but I don't know if it will break anything. Why would one need to use OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS? It seems Datastore supports ancestors and entity groups anyway in any mode (I don't think I'm using that feature anyway). Is it only necessary for App Engine 1st generation (e.g., Python 2 runtime)? I have switched to 2nd generation Python 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are really only three reasons why you want to stay with `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS`:

1. You need writes to be atomic within the whole entity-group. Consider this example:

   - One transaction accesses an entity `Foo/1/Bar/1` and a second, concurrent, transaction accesses `Foo/1/Bar/2`. Both these transactions touch different entities in the same entity group `Foo/1`.
   - Do you want both transactions to succeed? In that case you have to use `OPTIMISTIC` concurrency.
   - Or do you want one of the transactions to fail with "too much contention"? In that case you would need `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS`.
   - The most likely reason why you were migrated to `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS` is, that some of your transactions have failed in a scenario like this and the migration automation couldn't tell if you relied on this failure to occur. In other words, without knowing your code, it's impossible to say if a "contention failure" is a bug or feature to you. So the safe choice is not to change the behavior.
   - In order to answer that question, you would have to review your application logic and see what transactional guarantees you are relying on. This cannot be automated, but reasoning about this is probably not too hard for people familiar with the different modules of your application.
2. If you are using entity-group timestamps you also need `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS` - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/datastore/metadataqueries#entity_group_metadata

   - If this is the case, there is most likely a workaround. For example, you could transactionally write a timestamp yourself every time you make changes to an entity-group. This could potentially be sharded, so you wouldn't necessarily be creating a hot entity key.
   - This is also detected by the migration automation and could be another reason why you ended up with `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS`.
3. The last reason why you would need `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS` would be that you are using Datastore through the Remote API - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/tools/remoteapi

   - The Remote API relies on `OPTIMISTIC_WITH_ENTITY_GROUPS` and there are currently no plans to address that.
   - If you are using the Remote API without transactions and queries, you could still switch to `OPTIMISTIC` but this would be very risky, and you are better advised to find an alternative to the Remote API.

Except for these three reasons you are always better off with `OPTIMISTIC`. Here is some more information on how you can make the switch: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/upgrade-to-firestore#transactions

Comment: Thank you! Great answer with info not found anywhere else.